# How can I use new FontAwesome icons?

Tags: fontawesome5

In my cv/resume I would like to use the Font Awesome icon "fa-location-crosshairs".

According to [the icon's page](https://fontawesome.com/v6.0/icons/location-crosshairs?s=solid), it was added in version 5.2.0 of FontAwesome which was released in 2018. Unfortunately, although the LaTeX package fontawesome5 is supposed to be Font Awesome version 5.15.3, the icon is not listed in the documentation.

Still, as per the documentation, I tried converting to CamelCase and prefixing with \fa, which gives \faLocationCrosshairs, but XeLaTeX complains about an "undefined control sequence".

I then downloaded Font Awesome 5 fonts, renamed them as suggested in the docs, placed them in `C:\Program Files\TexLive\texmf-local\fonts\opentype` (that's where they belong, right?), and ran mktexlsr. Still no luck.

Is there another way I can still use this icon? My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\faLocationCrossHairs
\faCalendarDay
\faGlobe
\faAt

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further research led me to [a blog post](http://kumarcode.com/Adding-FontAwsome-icons-to-my-resume-using-Latex/) and an old  [fontawesome.sty](https://gist.github.com/sway/3101743) by someone called Honza Ustohal. It included notes on usage, which allowed me to adapt it, since I only wanted to add the one icon (I can use fontawesome5 for all other icons).

Apparently, the icon is only freely available in the desktop download of the new version of Font Awesome (version 6, which is still in beta, but ok). So I downloaded that version of the font, and simplified the code I found to:

```
\newfontfamily{\fa}{Font Awesome 6 Free-Solid-900.otf}
\newcommand{\faLocationCrossHairs}{\fa \symbol{"F601}}
```

The unicode for each icon can be found their page on fontawesome.com.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the [documentation for Font Awesome 5](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons), you see that in that version the icon wasn't called `location-crosshairs` but just [`location`](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/location?style=regular). Therefore the right command name would be `\faLocation`. Additionally this page shows that it's considered a "Pro" icon, so it's not included in the free version.

If you have the Pro version of the font, you can use it with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\faLocation
\faCalendarDay
\faGlobe
\faAt

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that explains things, thanks. Apparently, they changed their mind about making it a "pro" icon, as it is now again part of the free package in version 6 of Font Awesome.

Comment: "location" isn't the only icon whose name has changed in version 6. I just realized the "phone" icon has been flipped. To get old "phone" icon, you now need to use "phone-flipped".