# how to use a webfont in a Sphinx build environment?

Tags: fonts, sphinx

I'm building an extension for sphinx to include fontawesome icons inside documentation. It would be great if it could work in the LaTeX build as well. My initial work was relying on the "fontawesome5" package, but as we are now moving toward fa6 I would like to rely on the web font downloaded with from NPM.

**context**:

- builder is LaTeX (can be changed in the conf.py but that will lead to many errors in RDT)
- I have all the fonts in .ttf format
- I have the unicode of all my glyphs

I saw in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/627541/261930 the following command which is exactly what I need:

```latex
\newfontfamily{\fa}{Font Awesome 6 Free-Solid-900.ttf}
```

but It never works on my RDT environment (crash + no access to the logs). Can this really work? Uf yes, what should I install to make it work on my local machine ? (I can then tune the RDT env accordingly)

Comment: which compiler are you using? you need to configure your LaTeX builder to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead of pdflatex, since they support loading fonts from .ttf files.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the headstart [àscd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/183803/scd), I finally managed to make it work:

first step as you mentioned move to XeLaTex compiler:

```python
# conf.py
latex_engine = "xelatex"
```

Then use the fontspec package:

```python
# conf.py

setup(app):
    # [...]
    app.add_latex_package("fontspec")
```

and finally add the command to preamble:

```python
# conf.py

latex_elements["preamble"] += dedent(
    r"""
    \newfontfamily{\solid}{fa-solid-900.ttf}
    \newfontfamily{\regular}{fa-regular-400.ttf}
    \newfontfamily{\brands}{fa-brands-400.ttf}
    """
)
```

I can now use the following command in my Sphinx built latex output.

```latex
{\solid\symbol{"F07B}}
```

If people don't want to struggle as I did, I wrote 2 sphinx extention:

- https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-icon/ for inline icon support
- https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-btn/ for inline guilabel including icons

They support html and latex build

Comment: Under `latex_engine='xelatex'`, the `fontspec` package is automatically loaded.  I also don't think you need the `dedent()`.  Those extra spaces at start of lines are of no importance for LaTeX.  I would be interested to know how you inject the `\solid` mark-up.  Do you post-process the tex file

Comment: I use dedent to have a human readable preamble (the one generated by sphinx is already super packed). I don't quite understand the question about `\solid`. I use in the background a dedicated role that interprets icons and inject them in any build (epub, html, latex).

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I see now...